# How to automatically switch to another viewController after quiz ends (SWIFT)

Tags: swift, xcode

How to make automatic change viewController if I am using struct. I am new in Swift so please help to do that. I want after question number becomes 40 to change controller and view result.

```
struct IqBrain {
    let questions =  [

        Quiz (count:"1", image: "1", title: "Question", choice1: "38", choice2: "40", choice3: "42", choice4: "44", answer: "40"),  
        Quiz (count:"2", image: "2", title: "Question", choice1: "87", choice2: "90", choice3: "96", choice4: "98", answer: "90")

    ]
          
    var questionsNumber = 0
    var imageView = 0
    var score = 0

               
mutating func nextQuestion() -> Int {
    if questionsNumber + 1 < questions.count {
        questionsNumber += 1
    } else  {
        questionsNumber = 0 }
      return questionsNumber
    }

mutating func checkAnswer(_ userAnswer: String) -> Bool {
        if userAnswer == questions[questionsNumber].answer {
    score += 1
    //print ("right")
    return true
    } else {
    //print ("wrong")
      return false }
    }
```

Comment: What is the relation with this struct to view controller? Does the view controller have an instance of it?

Comment: Yes something like this:
 iqBrain.getQuestion()